# Connection string to access database in Program files

Tags: c#, winforms, database-connection, connection-string

I am working on windows form which uses microsoft access database.

When the application will be installed, the database will be on this location
C:\Program Files (x86)\Amrit\trial\Database.

How can i make this work so that this application will linked to the database when installed in my computer.

Can somebody give me easy solution..
Currently my connection string looks like this..

```
string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Users\\Amrit\\Desktop\\Database.accdb ;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

when i create setup file for appplication, the database will be in ProgramFiles/AmritCreations/AppName/Database.accdb

[image]

Comment: Please give more details.

Answer (score 1):

Just place your database and your application in the same directory and use this `connectionString`

```
string connString = "Provider=MICROSOFT.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " +
                    "Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Database.accdb";
```

In times you're creating a `Setup Project`, try to place the database file and [yourProjectName].exe in the same directory.

Comment: thats strange.. can you please give some more details about your problem? and when you use the `connectionString` from my answer.. what is the error?

Comment: before i can create setup file for the application, i changed the connection string as  string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|/Database.accdb ;Persist Security Info=False;"; and then i created the set up file where i put my databse in this location. ProgramFiles/AmritCreation/MyAppName/..

Comment: Did you try to place your database and your `application.exe` in the same folder?

Comment: Both are inside the My Product Name Directory..Please check pic above

Comment: okay.. again try to place your database file and your running application.exe in the same directory.. I mean try move your database file in that folder `Project Management`. or in `Bin` folder in the project solution and use the `connectionString` above